# owl carousel circular progress bar with classyloader gives a getContext error

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel-2

I'm trying to create a circular progress bar around dots in owl carousel and ClassyLoader (https://andy.su/classyloader/). All fine but I got stuck with this error `Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined`.

HTML

```
<div class="header-slider">
  <div class="header-slider-1">
    some slider content
  </div><!-- .header-slider-1 -->

  <div class="header-slider-2">
   some slider content
  </div><!-- .header-slider-2 -->

</div><!-- .header-slider -->

<div class="owl-dots" id="owldots">
  <div class="owl-dot"><canvas class="loader"></canvas><span></span></div>
  <div class="owl-dot"><canvas class="loader"></canvas><span></span></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* ------------------------- Owl settings -------------------------- */
  jQuery(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var timeout = 5000;
      var owl = $('.header-slider').owlCarousel({
          items: 1,
          dots: true,
          nav: false,
          loop:true,
          autoplay: true,
          autoplayTimeout: timeout,
          dotsContainer: '#owldots',
          onChanged: function () {
              $(function() {
                  var loader = $('.header-slider .owl-dot.active .loader').ClassyLoader({
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      percentage: 100,
                      speed: 20,
                      animate: true,
                      showRemaining: false,
                      showText: false,
                      diameter: 20,
                      lineColor: 'rgba(245,206,12,1)',
                      lineWidth: 2
                  });
              })
          }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Any idea how can I get this working?

Comment: Can you precise in which line do you get this error in your code (or precise the file name if in another file)? Also, why do you use `$(function() {` in your `onChanged` function? This syntax is used as an alias to `$(document).ready`..

Comment: Sorry I did't include this. The file you can see here(https://github.com/kab91/jquery-classyloader/blob/master/js/jquery.classyloader.js), and it's on line 41. Without `$(function()`  owl is not working.

Comment: Do you have a codepen/fiddle/anything where I could reproduce the issue? When I tried I had totally different errors

Comment: Please take a look at this https://codepen.io/Ricods/pen/zgRYod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, but the most important is: `ClassyLoader` must be instancied on a `canvas`, from the page you linked:

> Next, you create the canvas element on which you want to trigger the plugin.

Also as I stated in a comment, `$(function() { ... });` is an alias to `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`. And because in your code `$` is an alias to `jQuery`, it can be simplified. I personnally prefer document ready syntax, it's more evident what it does for future readers.

**NOTE:** you'll see in [the corrected codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OKQVNv) that you will probably have additional trouble with the CSS for your slides (they are not showing, probably conflict with owl carousel styles). I arbitrarily chose to set the canvas to `fixed` because it has to be a separate element and this will make it show upon the slides, but that can be improved. Note also that you need to use owl version 2 because of your syntax (changed your pen settings) and I directly copied `ClassyLoader` code because it doesn't work from filebin.

corrected code:

HTML:

```
<canvas class="header-loader"></canvas>
<div class="header-slider">
  <div class="header-slider-1">
    <p>some slider content 1</p>
  </div><!-- .header-slider-1 -->

  <div class="header-slider-2">
    <p>some slider content 2</p>
  </div><!-- .header-slider-2 -->
</div><!-- .header-slider -->

<div class="owl-dots" id="owldots">
  <div class="owl-dot"><canvas class="loader"></canvas><span></span></div>
  <div class="owl-dot"><canvas class="loader"></canvas><span></span></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { //you can also use "$(function() {" instead
  var timeout = 5000;
  var owl = $('.header-slider').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    dots: true,
    nav: false,
    loop:true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: timeout,
    dotsContainer: '#owldots',
    onChanged: function () {
      //don't use "$(function() {" here!
      var loader = $('.header-loader').ClassyLoader({ //changed the class
        width: 60,
        height: 60,
        percentage: 100,
        speed: 20,
        animate: true,
        showRemaining: false,
        showText: false,
        diameter: 20,
        lineColor: 'rgba(245,206,12,1)',
        lineWidth: 2
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Kaddath

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to display the `<canvas class="header-loader"></canvas>` after the owl-dot active so then with css I can make it look, as it is around it ? I have tried `if ($("div").hasClass("active")) {
      $("div.active").after("<canvas class="header-loader"></canvas>");
    }` but I had no luck